# How do i programmatically add 'people fields' in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, users, entities

I'm trying to programmatically add fields that are manually added here:

> /admin/config/people/accounts/fields

I'd want to add the fields when an admin enables my module/extension.

I've tried this in my MODULE.install file:

```
function openid_conect_enable() {
  field_cache_clear();
  field_associate_fields('user_alternative');

  //Given name field.
  if (!field_info_field('field_given_name')) {
    $field = array(
        'field_name' => 'field_given_name', 
        'type' => 'text', 
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    // Create the instance on the bundle.
    $instance = array(
        'field_name' => 'field_given_name', 
        'entity_type' => 'user', 
        'label' => 'Given Name', 
        'bundle' => 'user', 
        // If you don't set the "required" property then the field wont be required by default.
        'required' => TRUE,
        'settings' => array(
           // Here you inform either or not you want this field showing up on the registration form.
            'user_register_form' => 1,
        ),
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
        ),
        'display' => array(
          'default' => array('label' => 'above'),
      ),
    );
    field_create_instance($instance);
  }
}
```

but with no success.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34398477/295112 . The Drupal 7 code above will not work in Drupal 8.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any decent examples i can look at?

Comment: You won't find many examples for adding fields in php, because D8 introduced new methods for bundle fields. You can export and import fields with yaml files. Almost all core and contrib modules use only this method to install bundle fields. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215127/add-fields-to-user-entity-in-custom-module.

Comment: A good example of this is here. https://github.com/plach79/d8-active-users